# Java - How to change a 'local?' variable within an event listener

Tags: java, variables, event-handling

Got a quick question which I hope someone can answer. Basically I have a String variable which needs changing based upon the value in a combo box which has an event listener attached to it. However if I make the string final then it cant be changed, but if i don't make it final then eclipse moans that it isn't final. Whats the best (and simplest) work around?

Code is as follows

```
final String dialogOutCome = "";

//create a listener for the combo box
Listener selection = new Listener() {

    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    //get the value from the combo box
    String comboVal = combo.getText();

    switch (comboVal) {
         case "A": dialogOutCome = "a";
         case "B": dialogOutCome = "b";
         case "C": dialogOutCome = "c";
         case "D": dialogOutCome = "d";
    }
   }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

Consider this:

- the local variable exists as long as the method it's declared in runs.
- as soon as that method invocation ends (usually because the method exists) the variable vanishes
- the listener can (and usually does) live much longer

So what should happen when the method returned already and the listener tries to modify the local variable?

Because this question does not have a really good answer, they decided to make that scenario impossible by not allowing access to non-`final` local variables.

There are two ways around this problem:

- try to change a field instead of a local variable (this probably also fits better with the life-time of the listener) *or*
- use a `final` local variable, of which you can change the *content* (for example a `List` or a `String[]` with a single element).

Answer (score 3):

These answers are all telling you how to make a flawed approach "work" at a superficial level.

The real *problem* is that you're trying to apply traditional, synchronous, "call/return" coding patterns to a library that doesn't support it.  The real *answer* is that when the event you're waiting for happens asynchronously, the stuff you want to *do* after the event has to happen asynchronously as well.  Understanding the event-driven nature of Swing is vital to being effective in it.

In other words, think of what piece of code will read `dialogOutCome`.  Will some action be performed?  If so, perform that action *from the handler* (or as a result of the handler) instead.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use this approach.

```
public class ReturnValueListener implements Listener {

    private String dialogOutCome;

    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        //get the value from the combo box
        String comboVal = combo.getText();

        switch (comboVal) {
            case "A": dialogOutCome = " gay";
            ase "B": dialogOutCome = " ugly";
            case "C": dialogOutCome = " smelly";
            case "D": dialogOutCome = " great";
        }
    }

    public String getDialogOutCome() {
        return dialogOutCome;
    }
}

Listener selection = new ReturnValueListener();
//Set my listener somewhere,
....registerListener(selection);
//After my handleEvent is called
String dialogOutCome = selection.getDialogOutCome();
```

Comment: please starting with combo.getSelectedItem();, otherwise return nothing

Comment: @mKorbel, I don't quite follow.

Comment: @mKorbel, I understand what you're saying. I think the OP is using pseudocode here....

Answer (score 1):

Just create simple `StringWrapper` object:

```
static class StringWrapper {
       String value;

       StringWrapper(String value) {
           this.value = value;
       } 
}
```

and use it in type of field `dialogOutCome`:

```
final StringWrapper dialogOutCome = new StringWrapper("");

Listener selection = new Listener() {

    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        String comboVal = combo.getText();

        switch (comboVal) {
          case "A": dialogOutCome.value = " gay";
          case "B": dialogOutCome.value = " ugly";
          case "C": dialogOutCome.value = " smelly";
          case "D": dialogOutCome.value = " great";
        }
   }
};
```

Comment: please starting with combo.getSelectedItem();, otherwise return nothing

Comment: @mKorbel, sorry, I can't understand for whom you add this comment? If for me, then I'm just showing pattern in brief without details of correct deep implementation intended idea of author.

Comment: hmmm, pseudo_code created real mess, this question isn't about internal event from XxxComboBoxModel, but get String from XxxListener then doesn't make me any sence,

Comment: Hmm, now Eclipse is throwing a paddy over the StringWrapper class, its not allowed to be static, only public, final or abstract?

Comment: @user1987029 remove `static` modifier. It was just an example, I don't know where you put it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a setter for indirection.  This will take away the final restriction (since the field you're accessing is 'this' instead of 'dialogOutcome'.

```
String dialogOutCome = "";

void setOutcome(String value){
  dialogOutCome = value;
}

//create a listener for the combo box
Listener selection = new Listener() {

    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    //get the value from the combo box
    String comboVal = combo.getText();

    switch (comboVal) {
         case "A": setOutcome(" gay");
         case "B": setOutcome(" ugly");
         case "C": setOutcome(" smelly");
         case "D": setOutcome(" great");
    }
   }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Workaround solution: Use **StringBuilder** instead of `String`. Of course, `StringBuilder` cannot be changed reference in the `handleEvent`, but we could invoke its method.

```
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Listener selection = new Listener() {

        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        ...
        switch (comboVal) {
             case "A": sb.delete(0, sb.length()).append("a");
             case "B": sb.delete(0, sb.length()).append("b");
            ...
        }
       }
    };

...
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Then you could get String value by `StringBuilder.toString();`

*EDIT: Please provide the reason voting down this answer.*

Comment: This is *possible* but not good design: using a `StringBuilder` as a "mutable `String`" is an abuse of the class (note: I didn't downvote, but I guess that's the reason).

Comment: It's just workaround solution to fix the case. Sure, we could wrap a String in a class as mutable String.